# How To get Mega.py File Url From Folder Url

Tags: python

```
from mega import Mega
mega = Mega()

m = mega.login()

folderlink = "https://mega.nz/folder/prJmGKRK#Wyp6DjoQIvykCRXJ5p734w"
```

I want to get each file URL from the folder link like a:

```
link1 = "https://mega.nz/file/U3QEiDjB#ZKGRnuvN86dh7K9j5WK9nl4A2gS3k-ReTb9P0F1t_Pg1"
link2 = "https://mega.nz/file/U3QEiDjB#ZKGRnuvN86dh7K9j5WK9nl4A2gS3k-ReTb9P0F1t_Pg2"
link3 = "https://mega.nz/file/U3QEiDjB#ZKGRnuvN86dh7K9j5WK9nl4A2gS3k-ReTb9P0F1t_Pg3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution but you have to import the folder into your mega (not sure can we do it without import):

```py
mega = Mega()
m = mega.login('<your email id>', '<your password>')
folder = m.find("novels")[0]
files = m.get_files_in_node(folder)

print(len(files))

for file in list(files.items()):
    print(file)
    link = m.get_link(file)
    print(link)
    #time.sleep(1)
```

This finds the folder named novels first, and gets all public URLs for the files. You can also use `m.get_files()` to get all files.

''' strfile = list(file)
if not (strfile[1]['t']) == 0:
continue
size=file[1]['s']
name = file[1]['a']['n']
name = bytes(name, encoding="raw_unicode_escape", errors="ignore").decode()  '''
Add this for getting filename and size and type. I decoded the filename since some Languages came as encoded..